# Where is the fuse for the front windshield washer pump on a '09 Chevy Traverse?

Tags: chevrolet, windshield-washer

On my '09 Chevy Traverse, the windshield washer pump stopped working on both the front and back. I first checked for fuses. There was one in the fuse block under the hood, that one looked good. I found another under the dash on the passenger side (what a PITA to get at). That one was blown. I replaced that one and now the rear works. When I try the front, I hear a click (a relay?) but nothing else happens. Any idea if there is another fuse somewhere label incorrectly or where I should look next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I replaced my pump... and it still didn't work. After doing some more looking I discovered that I read the fuse map wrong and put the fuse in the wrong spot. After putting it in the right spot it started to work. Since I know you can't take used electronic parts back, I just kept it in and kept the old one.

BTW, to get at the pump, you have to remove the wheel and open up the wheel well.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the pump is seized? This could also cause the fuses to blow.

Comment: I am not ruling it out, but I don't want to take it to the shop to find out that it was a fuse. $50 fuses get spendy quick.

Comment: Do you know how to jump your pump, and bypass? That's the easy way of checking. 12V battery can do it.